# Identifying the location of a given thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

After identifying a particular thread of interest, is it possible to programmatically get its location at runtime?

In other words, I want to see which method this thread is currently executing:

> var executingThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;

I know I can find this information in the Threads window when debugging in VisualStudio, but I'm stumped as to whether this is possible to obtain in code.

My goal is to periodically log the location of a thread I'm monitoring in a long running process.

Comment: `Thread.CurrentThread` will always be the thread doing the logging at the point that the logger decides to get off its lazy butt.

Comment: @Dan-o: I'm using a timer to spawn a new thread to periodically monitor the executing thread. This seems to work well enough to make sure the thread is still alive, but I want more! :)

Comment: even if you could, there's really no point, the current thread will always be executing the code to figure out what method is running.  If you're talking about another thread, not really because you trying to look at an executing thread, by the time you return from such a method that thread may be on to executing another method.

Comment: @Peter: True, but I'm not trying to make any decisions based on what information that returns. I'm merely trying to get a sense for where the thread is getting hung up for long periods of time. I realize that my logging should be capturing this, I was really just curious if this was possible as it might provide some insight into something I might be missing.

Comment: @chris well, that's making a decision :).  But seriously, you'd be introducing a race condition by definition.  You could observe MethodX when you look, but it was spending most of its time in MethodY.  What you want to do can be done with debggers and profilers--those will be your best bet and most reliable.

Comment: @Peter: For sure, point taken. I guess I wasn't as concerned with the race condition if I'm polling every 30 seconds and the methods are taking hours to complete. You're right, it seems pointless because I would know where things were getting hung up. It was mostly my interest in being thorough, but perhaps just a simple check for IsAlive is sufficient.

Comment: I've never found any need for such checking.  IME, it's fairly easy to work out which thread/task is stuck/looping from the symptoms and debugger. 'IsAlive' etc. does not mean 'working correctly' and adding more code inevitably adds more bugs, more testing and more maintenance :(  Spending that time on fixing bugs in 'real' code is likely to me more productive.

Comment: @Martin: Agreed...in the beginning, I was more interested in seeing if the thread was actually doing something more than what it was actually doing. But as I was working it out, I thought it could be helpful to log the location in the event it might be helpful for quickly diagnosing a problem when running live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be introducing a race condition by definition--by the time another thread observed that the observed thread *was* executing `MethodX` it could have moved on to `MethodY`--since it would be continually running. Or, you could observe `MethodX` when you look, but it was spending most of its time in `MethodY`.  What you want to do can be done with debuggers and profilers--those will be your best bet and most reliable.